# How to prove that there exists a bijection between R and C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So how can I prove that there exists a bijection between R (real numbers) and C (complex numbers)
I think that I should prove that there exists a bijection between RxR and C which is not too hard and then find a bijection between R  and RxR, but isn't there a simple solution to find a direct bijection between C and R?
P.s: I'm in terminal highschool so I'm fairly ignorant about set theory.

Comment: I want to find a direct bijection not one that goes from R -> RxR and then RxR-> C, so I think my question is a bit different

Comment: If $f\colon X\to Y$ is a bijection, $f^{-1}\colon Y\to X$ is a bijection too.

Comment: @Lazarus The composition of these functions is a direct bijection.